# How to use objects as scalars or cell arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, object, svm, image-recognition

I am trying a code in MATLAB which is aimed to recognize handwritten digits using the Support Vector Machine classifier.

The entire code is given here:

https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab-computer-vision/mw/vision-ex68788140-digit-classification-using-hog-features

I am having issues with this line

```
[testFeatures, testLabels] = helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet(testSet, hogFeatureSize, cellSize);
```

I get this error:

"Array formation and parentheses-style indexing with objects of class 'matlab.io.datastore.ImageDatastore' is not allowed.  Use objects of class 'matlab.io.datastore.ImageDatastore' only as scalars or use a cell array."

I tried using this but still not working:

```
testFeatures = helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet(testSet, hogFeatureSize, cellSize);
testLabels = helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet(testSet, hogFeatureSize, cellSize);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am new to MATLAB and I currently try some new codes for object recognition.

Comment: There is no issue with the code that Mathworks has provided.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I ran it like a week ago!

Comment: Good, I will try to run it again. Allow me to say thanks.